# How install keras-bert by pip? (No matching distribution found)

Tags: python, keras, pip, conda, bert-language-model

I am new to Python dependency management and installation. I wanna run some code from GitHub for my experiment. However, I got stuck while installing `keras-bert`. I can't install either using `pip` or `conda`. Below is the result for attempting to install via `pip`.

*Any idea what is going wrong and how to fix it?*

### Error Message

```bash
(biobert_zhu) jupyter-23520037@tambora:~/j191015$ pip install keras-bert
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy', SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)')))': /simple/keras-bert/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy', SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)')))': /simple/keras-bert/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy', SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)')))': /simple/keras-bert/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy', SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)')))': /simple/keras-bert/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy', SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)')))': /simple/keras-bert/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keras-bert (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for keras-bert
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

### Additional Details

I am running on Linux.

Comment: It appears you would have trouble with _any_ `pip install` package, even simple ones, as you lack https connectivity to internet servers. Verify with lynx or curl that you can visit https URLs. Use `$ env | sort | grep -i proxy` to verify that you're not pointing web clients at some proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable to make sure it starts with `http://`

You can read more [here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-usage.html#your-proxy-appears-to-only-use-http-and-not-https)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).